# How to deal with being away from moderating for extended periods of time?

Tags: user-behavior

I have a sub in which the other mods are not entirely reliable. There is a spam filter and the sub runs smoothly for the most part without moderation, but is/are there better ways than to just hope for the best?

Comment: See if you can get somebody else that you trust to fill in for you.

Comment: Your usage of "sub" makes me think this is dealing with the Reddit platform. Is this correct?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know how moderators are appointed (and replaced) in your community. The underlying problem is, after all, the other moderators' lack of reliability.

Comment: @Andy that is correct

Comment: @FEichinger I am the head moderator so I have the power to appoint and replace at my own free will. But when I say that other mods are not entirely reliable, it is not that they are bad mods. It is just that, well you know, most people have lives and the other mods ability to moderate is not always consistent.

Comment: How many mods do you have?  Is that number typical for your community's size, activity level, and community type?  How long an absence are you talking about -- and just one, or recurring?  Adding these details would strengthen your question and help us give better answers.  Thanks.

Comment: I've closed this question because it is missing details that can narrow the scope of possible answers. There are a few things that would help narrow the scope: a.) Information about how many other moderators there are, b.) information about your leave of absence (is it one time, recurring, taking place over a long weekend or a month), c.) community size and activity level. All of these details are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two styles of moderation that I can think of right now, so I'll try to address them both.

### Time-based moderation

My go-to would be to find some sort of protégé in the mod community and actually and publicly charge him/her with your moderation duties for the term.  This way, people know who to come to and there is an explicit sense of responsibility on the person you charge.

### Big Ball of Modly-Wobbly Stuff

This one is trickier.  There's no real single source of responsibility here.  In this case though, I think the mod community will be able to handle one person leaving (depending on how large it is).  If it is very small, the time-based suggestion should work, too.

Answer (score 3):

> in which the other mods are not entirely reliable

**First of all,** is there anything you can do about this? You have bigger problems than taking a vacation if this is true. If you have several examples of them acting up, you can tell a higher-up person. If you don't feel like you can trust the other moderators, then it might be best to *just leave*.

Other than that:

- See if you can check in every day or two sometime (maybe at night). I don't know where you're going, so this might not always be an option.
- If there's a mod on an unrelated part of the site that you trust, you might ask them to help. You could phrase it to be a *temporary substitute* so you don't *"stress the other moderators."* :)

You need to either fix this situation or get out of it as soon as you can. Not trusting the other mods is a bad thing and can hurt your reputation and your site that you moderate.

Comment: Very good point about trusting the other mods.  It is exactly trusting your teammates; you can't operate effectively without this trust.

Comment: There is too sides to trust “trust not to do something bad” and “trust to visit the site and do something”.